# How to get only last commit of a git repository

Tags: git, repository, clone, commit

I want to clone locally only the last commit of a remote git repository. I need this because the full clone fails (I think it is due to the huge size of the repository). Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is. Have I to close the question or do I leave it here for references? Thanks

Comment: You didn't read the Help Centre as instructed, then?